# Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, openstreetmap

I'm working with pbf files from the open street maps

I want to parse node, relations, and ways.

when I try to parse nodes I get that message.

The code looks like

```
package myCode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import protpbufCode.OsmPbf;
import protpbufCode.OsmPbf.Node;
import protpbufCode.OsmPbf.PrimitiveGroup;


public class ReadingPBF 
{

     public static void print(PrimitiveGroup node)
      {
           for (Node m: node.getNodesList()) 
            {
              System.out.print("Person ID: " + m.getId() + " ");
              System.out.print("  Lat: " + m.getLat()+ " ");
              System.out.print(" Long: "+ m.getLon()+ " ");
              System.out.println("");

            }
      }


    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        try 
        {
            PrimitiveGroup newNode = PrimitiveGroup.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(new         File("isle.pbf")));
            print(newNode);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }



    }
}
```

the OsmPbf is java class that created using the protobuf compiler.

and that what gets printed.

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
at     com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:158)
at protpbufCode.OsmPbf$PrimitiveGroup.<init>(OsmPbf.java:5230)
at protpbufCode.OsmPbf$PrimitiveGroup.<init>(OsmPbf.java:5219)
at protpbufCode.OsmPbf$PrimitiveGroup$1.parsePartialFrom(OsmPbf.java:5329)
at protpbufCode.OsmPbf$PrimitiveGroup$1.parsePartialFrom(OsmPbf.java:1)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:192)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:209)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:215)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
at protpbufCode.OsmPbf$PrimitiveGroup.parseFrom(OsmPbf.java:5627)
at myCode.ReadingPBF.main(ReadingPBF.java:33)


Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

null
```

Comment: Did you check if the PBF file is broken? Can it be read with other tools, like [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)?

Comment: yes i checked , it is not broken.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap .pbf files are not simple protobufs. See the documentation here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format

Under the section "File format", you'll see this:

> The format is a repeating sequence of:
>
> - int4: length of the BlobHeader message in network byte order
> - serialized BlobHeader message
> - serialized Blob message (size is given in the header)

That is, the file starts out with a 4-byte integer before the first protobuf message. Since this integer is probably smaller than 2^24, the first byte will of course be zero, which explains the exact exception you are seeing.

You will need to read this 4-byte value manually, then make sure to read only that many bytes and parse them as a `BlobHeader`, and so on.

Personally I'd recommend looking for a PBF decoder library that already handles this for you. There must be a few out there.